# Help identify this Raleigh bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

New to Bikes so hoping this question is OK.

My partner was recently given an old Raleigh bike for free and has since taken it to get the cables and tyres replaced, but as it's quite small (for teens?) she plans to trade / swap / sell it for something more her size.

I know nothing about bikes whatsoever, but apparently the people in the repair shop said it's quite unique. Can anyone tell me anything else about it? Era / 'model' / history or the like?

[image: Raleigh Right hand side]

[image: Raleigh bike]

[image: Close up]

[image: Badge]

Comment: The main dating item is the cottered crank.  This tells you it's prior to about 1975.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *Jeep* is a giveaway.  There really was a Raleigh Jeep.  [It's on page 7 of this 1971 catalogue](http://threespeedhub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Raleigh-Catalog-1971-UK1.pdf).

You're right, it was meant for girls.

That massive headlight isn't original.  Otherwise it's a nice looking bike that needs some work.

Comment: It really is a bit of a giveaway, isn't it?

Comment: Hahah, feel a bit daft now! Good to know for certain anyway.

Comment: The massive headlight is about right for the period though, when incandescent lamps were driven by two D cell batteries.   There's no rear light visible at all, and no reflectors other than what's on the much-more-recent pedals, or perhaps painted white on the back of the mudguard.

Comment: @Criggie specifically I think the lamp is an [Ever Ready Frontguard](https://www.ebay.ie/itm/VINTAGE-EVER-READY-FRONT-CYCLE-Clear-LAMP-LIGHT-BIKE-1970s-Chopper-Bicycle-/223020504774?hash=item33ed0ed6c6) so not standard equipment but as you say correct for the period

Comment: What's with the gashes and blood on the legs of the kids on page 5?

Answer (score 2):

Not unique (ChrisH has already nailed it), but unusual, and possibly rare.  What it won't be is valuable.  You have the bicycle equivalent of a 1970s manually-tuned push-button TV.  Kind of fun, but kind of clunky by modern standards.

Comment: I reckon it could make a nice project bike for someone the right size.  But that's not exactly a big market, so you're right.

Comment: Interesting for a collector, maybe? Are there even bicycle collectors?

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz Are there bikers who _aren't_ collectors? [The correct number of bikes to own is n+1 or s-1](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#12)

Answer (score 2):

I had one of these bikes for Xmas in 1971, it was my pride and joy. I seem to remember that it had white tyres, and the saddle was white plastic. It didn’t have the light on the front, or the rear carry frame when it was new, they must have been extras.

Answer (score 0):

I had one of these about 30years ago - I was about 23 but I'm small so the bike was lovely.  I had the red frame and blue mud and chain guards which I then sprayed matt black.  I also put white walled tyres on it.  It looked amazing but the lack of any gears was a real bind.  My partner got one, second hand, for Christmas in the early 70s and was so excited.  There are still a lot sbout and you can still pick them up for £20-40.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Exchange. This is not considered an answer but is more of a comment. When you gain more reputation you can comment on questions and answers.